# makefile not detecting new save file

Tags: makefile

Strange thing happening:

The idea of the makefile is to be able to compile several files at the same time. If you edit one of those files, when you type `make`, the only file that should compile is the one that was edited.

Now, for some reason, my makefile has decided to stop recognizing when the file has changed. So I have to: `make clean` and the `make` again to be able to compile, which is ridiculous since each time I have to compile takes about 1 minute.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I didn't add anything to my makefile; it just started doing that out of nowhere.

Comment: Something changed; programs don't stop working unless something changed.  The difficulty is going to be working out what changed.  You can always just type `rm file-that-changed.o; make` to rebuild just the one file that changed, but that's a nuisance.  Is there a multi-step compilation and you have an intermediate file lying around that is confusing `make`? You should reduce this to a simple makefile with two source files, one of which doesn't get recompiled and one of which does. Show us that, and the directory listing just those files. You'll probably resolve your problem before posting.

Comment: Thanks jonathan! yeah I just had a little mix up in the multi-setp compilation. Guess i am a little tired after so many hours of work.

Answer (score 2):

Something changed; programs don't stop working unless something changed. The difficulty is going to be working out what changed. You can always just type:

```
 rm file-that-changed.o
 make
```

to rebuild just the one file that changed, but that's a nuisance.

Is there a multi-step compilation and you have an intermediate file lying around that is confusing `make`?

> I just had a mix up in a multi-step compilation.

---

If you have a non-standard file suffix that you compile into C code, and then from C into object code (or any other similar multi-step compilation), then the key to getting reliable recompilation with [`make`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) is to organize the suffix list so that your extensions come at the start.  Unfortunately, there isn't a standard easy way to know what the built-in suffix list is, so you end up having to do something like this:

```
SUFFIXES     = .y .l .c .o       # Yacc, Lex, C, Object files
EXTRA_SUFFIX = .xc               # Extreme C, or Extended C, or ...

.SUFFIXES:                       # Eliminate all built-in suffixes
.SUFFIXES: ${EXTRA_SUFFIX} ${SUFFIXES}
```

The second `.SUFFIXES` line puts your extension at the front of the list.  Now you can write your rules to compile your `.xc` file into a `.c` or `.o` file, and then when you modify the `.xc` file, even if there's an intermediate `.c` file left around, the fact that the `.xc` is newer than the `.c` or `.o` file will ensure that the recompilation is done.

Once upon a long time ago, the Sun version of `make` provided a macro called SUFFIXES which contained the default suffixes in the correct order.  Sadly, that was not adopted and standardized, so you have to build the suffix list yourself.  But the choice of macro name wasn't entirely accidental.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that the the order of the suffix list was important.